# CURL Lfo errors from Windows Powershell

Tags: docker, docker-compose, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

So I tried installing an airflow docker compose file through powershell and it is giving me an error
this is my input
curl -LfO 'https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.0.1/docker-compose.yaml'

the error message goes this way
Invoke-WebRequest : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'LfO'.
At line:1 char:6

- curl -LfO 'https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.0.1/docke ...
- ```
   ~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

Answer (score 2):

I got same error.
In my case, the curl command in the Power shell was an alias for Invoke-WebRequest.
It looks like the same cause in your case.

```
> Get-Alias curl

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Alias           curl -> Invoke-WebRequest
```

So you can solve this by changing your options.

```
> curl -O docker-compose.yaml 'https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.0.1/docker-compose.yaml'
```

Thank you